# Backup > Restore to New Farm > My site does not resolve

Tags: my-site, web-application, dns

I have a Dev farm and I restored (SP restore) my site web application. After this, I went to use profile service and reconfigured "My site host". When I type the dev url for mysite it does not resolve. However, port 80 for the same web app resolves and i can all the site collections.

Error i get is "could not connect to intranetDev.company.com:7500. Any suggestions? however, intranetDev.company.com resolves because dns entry is there and it's on port 80.

I did this but long time ago. I forgot whether I need to have my Network guy put a new DNS entry for 8080.

Do I need to do anything in the "Service Connections" for mysite web app? right now only "App registry svc" and "wss usage app" is checked.

Thanks

Comment: yes, you need a DNS entry before you can use `mysite-dev.company.com:7500`. What happens when you use `localhost:7500`?

Comment: Mike: Sorry, I miss-typed the url. the portal and mysite is same url just 80 and 8080. machinename:8080 gives me 400, bad request-invalid hostname

Comment: What does the AAM look like? Can you post that?

Comment: http://intranetDev.company.com:8080 default http://intranetDev.company.com:8080

and

http://intranetDev:8080 Intranet http://intranetDev:8080

Comment: did you disable loop checkback? http://msmvps.com/blogs/laflour/archive/2009/06/09/sharepoint-tip-36-do-you-know-a-cause-of-http-400-bad-request-error-when-login-to-site.aspx

Comment: yes lookback is disabled

Comment: I see "No User Profile Application available to service the request." when i try to access the mysite from app server. User profile service configured for admin n permission like this link suggests http://jopx.blogspot.com/2011/08/solving-no-user-profile-application.html

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7187/discussion-between-mike-and-maria-burton)

Comment: Hi Mike, I notice only 2 svc was in the service connection. I added all of them and wala. It's working now. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: the chat isn't working for some reason. the mysite isn't accessible from outside the app server box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I gathered, you need to make sure that your service connections are either all checked, or set to the default service connection group.

You may need to open up the 8080 port in your firewall to accept incoming requests..

Comment: Basically, Add an entry in the Load balancer appliance for port 8080. Now it's all fine. Thanks for all your help.